# What was the Rabbinic position toward the armed revolts against the Romans?

Tags: history, rabbis, army-military-war

> "...Rabbi Yosei, son of Rabbi Ḥanina said: Why are these three oaths needed? One, so that the Jews should not ascend to Eretz Yisrael as a wall. And another one, that **the Holy One, Blessed be He, adjured the Jews that they should not rebel against the rule of the nations of the world**. ... [Ketubot.111a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ketubot.111a.3?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Regarding this interpretation: was it the official Rabbinic approach to the Great Revolt of 66CE and Bar-Kochbah Revolt in 132CE or was it instituted aposteriori? Do our sources discuss different approaches to the conflict, as I remember R' Akiva described as serving Bar Kochbah?

Comment: Josephus describes some of the sages who took part in the Revolt. Most curiously, just the other day I saw an interpretation of the name of one of the faction leaders in Yerushalayim that it may refer to none other than Rabbi Zechariah Ben Avkulas, which hypothetically might shed a different light on his indecision with regards to the story of Kamtza and Bar Kamtza. Rabban Shimon ben Gamliel the first, if I remember correctly, also had a more active, pro-war position. He was eventually killed, either by another faction or by the Romans.

Comment: I've also heard that the reason that Rabban Gamliel II is missing from the Seder in Bnei Brak is because they gathered there, in Rabbi Akiva's hometown, to plan the Bar Kochva Revolt and R"G was against it.